simple-peer conflict with react + vite, videochat

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import Peer from "simple-peer";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Video = ({ peer }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
      ref.current.srcObject = stream;
    });

    return () => {
      peer.removeAllListeners("stream");
    };
  }, [peer]);

  return <video playsInline autoPlay ref={ref} />;
};

const videoConstraints = {
  height: window.innerHeight / 2,
  width: window.innerWidth / 2,
};

const Room = () => {
  const { roomID } = useParams();
  const [peers, setPeers] = useState([]);
  const socketRef = useRef();
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const peersRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io("http://localhost:8000");

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: videoConstraints, audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        console.log("Stream obtained:", stream);
        userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
        socketRef.current.emit("join room", roomID);

        socketRef.current.on("all users", (users) => {
          // console.log(users);
          const peers = [];
          users.forEach((userID) => {
            const peer = createPeer(userID, socketRef.current.id, stream);
            peersRef.current.push({
              peerID: userID,
              peer,
            });
            peers.push(peer);
          });
          setPeers(peers);
        });

        socketRef.current.on("user joined", (payload) => {
          const peer = addPeer(payload.signal, payload.callerID, stream);
          peersRef.current.push({
            peerID: payload.callerID,
            peer,
          });

          setPeers((users) => [...users, peer]);
        });

        socketRef.current.on("receiving returned signal", (payload) => {
          const item = peersRef.current.find((p) => p.peerID === payload.id);
          item.peer.signal(payload.signal);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error accessing media devices.", error);
      });
  }, []);

  function createPeer(userToSignal, callerID, stream) {
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: true,
      trickle: false,
      stream: stream,
    });

    peer.on("signal", (signal) => {
      socketRef.current.emit("sending signal", {
        userToSignal,
        callerID,
        signal,
      });
    });

    return peer;
  }

  function addPeer(incomingSignal, callerID, stream) {
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: false,
      trickle: false,
      stream,
    });

    peer.on("signal", (signal) => {
      socketRef.current.emit("returning signal", { signal, callerID });
    });

    peer.signal(incomingSignal);

    return peer;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <video playsInline autoPlay muted ref={userVideo} />
      {peers.map((peer, index) => {
        return <Video key={index} peer={peer} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Room;

ok let's begin. I'm getting 2 types of errors.
first when I define window.global = window manually in vite.config
define: {
    global: {},
 },

the error occurs:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser.
Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11

then when I remove it from vite.config no matter what I try I get this error every time a second user tries to connect to the room using the same link:
Uncaught DOMException: Cannot set remote answer in state stable
Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot signal after peer is destroyed

I'm using vite-plugin-node-polyfills btw, because it solves another bug
plugins: [react(), nodePolyfills({ protocolImports: true })],
here is my nestjs backend if you need it
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  OnGatewayInit,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

interface Room {
  id: string;
  participants: string[];
}

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
export class VideoGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  private users: any = {};
  private socketToRoom: any = {};

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    console.log('WebSocket server started');
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    const roomID = this.socketToRoom[client.id];
    let room = this.users[roomID];
    if (room) {
      room = room.filter((id) => id !== client.id);
      this.users[roomID] = room;
    }
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('join room')
  handleJoinRoom(client: Socket, roomID: string): void {
    if (this.users[roomID]) {
      const length = this.users[roomID].length;
      if (length === 4) {
        client.emit('room full');
        return;
      }
      this.users[roomID].push(client.id);
    } else {
      this.users[roomID] = [client.id];
    }
    this.socketToRoom[client.id] = roomID;
    const usersInThisRoom = this.users[roomID].filter((id) => id !== client.id);

    client.emit('all users', usersInThisRoom);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('sending signal')
  handleSignal(
    client: Socket,
    payload: { userToSignal: string; signal: any; callerID: string },
  ): void {
    this.server.to(payload.userToSignal).emit('user joined', {
      signal: payload.signal,
      callerID: payload.callerID,
    });
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('returning signal')
  handleReturningSignal(
    client: Socket,
    payload: { callerID: string; signal: any },
  ): void {
    this.server.to(payload.callerID).emit('receiving returned signal', {
      signal: payload.signal,
      id: client.id,
    });
  }
}

tried
<script>
      window.global = window;
</script>

in the index.html, then get
Uncaught DOMException: Cannot set remote answer in state stable
Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot signal after peer is destroyed

find out that
const item = peersRef.current.find((p) => p.peerID === payload.id);
here I get nothing in the item but I still don't understand how to solve it
